# React deploy update (GH-pages)

Tags: reactjs, git, github, deployment, github-pages

I've already deployed my React App to GitHub Pages for the first time a couple days ago but I was wondering about what if I wanted to change something in my app and I need to push my deploy.

I already pushed a small change in my responsive design two days ago with GIT to my GitHub but nothing was modified in my GH page. I'm thinking about writing "npm run build" and "npm run deploy" once again but honestly, I'm scared in case I screw it and I want to ask you guys.

What can I do to update my React App in my GH page?  Shall I use git push anyways? "npm run build" and deploy? Do I have to do something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy it on vercel. It is free and takes only a few clicks to set up.

It also creates a pipeline so when you push a new change in your repository it automatically deploys it.

Comment: Hi, never heard of Vercel before, so I'll try it out. Thanks!